# Linear Algebra A Level Complex Number Magnitude Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, complex-numbers

Any ideas how to prove this inequality of any two complex numbers?

$$ ||z| - |w||\leq|z + w |$$

My intuition told me to square both sides:

$$ (|z| - |w|) ^ 2 \leq |z + w|^2 \\ |z|^2 - 2|z||w| + |w|^2 \leq |(z + w)(z+w)| \\z \bar z - 2|z||w| + w \bar w \leq |zz+2wz + ww|
$$ In polar complex notation $ z = a + ib, w = c + id$ where $ a,b,c,d \ \epsilon \ R: $
$$ a^2+b^2 - 2\sqrt {a^2+b^2} \sqrt{c^2 + d^2} + c^2 + d^2 \leq |a^2 + 2abi-b^2 + 2((ac-bd) + (bc + ad)i) + c^2 + 2cdi - d^2| $$ 
Simplify RHS in polar complex notation:
$$ |a^2 + c^2 - (b^2 + d^2) + 2ac - 2bd + 2(bc + ad + cd + ab)i| $$

If I take the magnitude of the RHS, maybe the terms can cancel out the LHS and become something like: $$0\leq a^2 + b^2$$
Then it becomes obvious that the inequality is true. Is expanding a reasonable technique or is there a better way to prove this?

Comment: Consider 2 concentric circles with radius $|z|$ and $|w|$. From a point on one circle, the nearest point on the other circle has what distance away?

Comment: Note that this holds for any quantities that satisfy the triangle inequality, in particular, norms.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way is to note the difference form $|z+w| \ge |z| - |w|$ of the triangle inequality*. Similarly we have $|z+w|=|w+z| \ge |w|-|z|$. Together these imply $|z+w|\ge\max\{|z| - |w|,|w|-|z|\} = \big| |z|-|w| \big|$.

*It's worth remembering why $|z+w| \ge |z| - |w|$ is a version of the triangle inequality: it's because $|z| = |(z+w)-w| \le |z+w|+|-w| = |z+w|+|w|$.

Answer (score 1):

By the triangle inequality, $|z| = |(z + w) - w| \leq |z + w| + |w|$, so $|z|-|w|\leq |z+w|$.

Interchanging $z$ and $w$ then gives $-(|z|-|w|)\leq |z+w|$.

This means that both $|z|-|w|$ and its opposite are no more than $|z+w|$. In particular,
$-\Big||z|-|w|\Big| \leq \underbrace{\Big||z|-|w|\Big| \leq |z + w|}_\textrm{what you want to show}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $w=0$ or $z=0$ the result is trivial. Without loss of generality assume $0<|z|\le |w|$ and take $Z=z/w,$ then $0<|Z|\le 1$ and we need to show that $$1\le|Z|+|Z+1|.$$ Draw the triangle whose vertices are $0, Z$ and $Z+1$ and use the fact that "the sum of the lengths of any two sides of a triangle must be greater than or equal to the length of the remaining side."

Comment: A shorther way is to create triangle with vertices at origin, $z$, and $-w$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja: May be, yes. But, then you would have to use the "Geometric triangle inequality" twice. I though reducing the general case to a single variable case would be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the three segments connecting origin, $z$, and $-w$. The difference in length between any two of these cannot exceed the length of the third segment.

Equality occurs when the origin, $z$, and $-w$ are collinear with the origin not in between